# What is the correct placement of "End with" and "Next"

Tags: excel, vba

This is a followup to a previous question. I am trying to create a copy/paste macro involving a drop down on one tab and sumifs on another. I want the macro to (in order)
1 plug in a value on the drop down tab and let the formulas calc.
2 go to the other tab paste the corresponding row as values.
3 repeat 1-2 for the next drop down value

Is the end with/next in the right place for the macro to do what I need?

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
Sheets("MS Wall Summary Weekly View").Activate
    Dim vRws As Long, vRng As Range
    Dim d As Range, d8 As Range, Wst As Worksheet
    Dim vRng2 As Range, vRws2 As Long, i As Long

Set Wst = Worksheets("MS Wall Summary Weekly View")
Set d8 = Wst.Range("D8")

With Wst
   vRws = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set vRng = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(vRws, "A"))

For Each d In vRng.Cells

d8 = d
Sheets("Email").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    vRws2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 8 To vRws2
        Set vRng2 = .Range(.Cells(i, "U"), .Cells(i, "AC"))
            vRng2.Copy
                vRng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Next d
   Next i
End With
End With
```

The first picture corresponds to the first part of the macro. The drop down in is Col. A and it gets plugged into D8
[image]

This second picture is on the "email tab". The sumifs are based on cell D8 in the first tab. I want one row starting in U8:AC8 pasted as a value.

[image]

Comment: When posting code, please *indent* it so it's readable - that will also help you with your placement...

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not super familiar with VBA best practices

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?608301-What-is-indenting-and-why-should-I-do-it

Comment: i guess you have to change places of the "next d" and "next i" if you indent your code it will be easier to see the problems.